# MACRO to covert string time format into minutes

Tags: excel, vba

[REFER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upn1M.png)

As in that image I want to convert 1 hrs 41 Mins into 101 as minutes.kindly help me with macro VBA.

Comment: Can you post at least 10 of your data to the question instead of an image?

Comment: Why a macro? formula can do this easily using Left Right and Find functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Davies mentioned, you can do this with formulas.

Assuming the initial text is always formatted as you showed in your image, the following formula should work:
`=(LEFT(A1,FIND("hr",A1)-1)*60)+MID(A1,FIND("hr",A1)+3,3) & " mins"`

Of course, if you insist on using a macro, the following code can be used to convert the active cell (the macro works better in the sense that it accepts more flexible formatting (e.g. "1 hr10mins" works with the macro but not with the formula)):

```
Sub ConvertToMins()
    Dim mins As Integer
    Dim SearchString  As String
    Dim hourLength As Integer
    Dim minPos As Integer

    mins = 0
    SearchString = ActiveCell.Text

    If InStr(1, SearchString, " h", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        hourLength = InStr(1, SearchString, " h", vbTextCompare) - 1
    ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "h", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        hourLength = InStr(1, SearchString, "h", vbTextCompare) - 1
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    mins = mins + (CDbl(Left(SearchString, hourLength)) * 60)

    If InStr(1, SearchString, " m", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        minPos = InStr(1, SearchString, " m", vbTextCompare) - 2
    ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "m", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        minPos = InStr(1, SearchString, "m", vbTextCompare) - 2
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = CStr(mins) & " mins"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsNumeric(Mid(SearchString, minPos, 2)) = True Then
        mins = mins + (CInt(Mid(SearchString, minPos, 2)))
    Else
        mins = mins + (CInt(Mid(SearchString, minPos, 1)))
    End If

    ActiveCell.Value = CStr(mins) & " mins"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks thts working cool....  but the thng is i wanted it to loop through all cells in range of C2:C22 in all my sheets of workbook this code is working for nly active cell. @Zachary Lim